# BRST quantization (Green, Schwarz, Witten)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, operators, brst, ghosts

In Green, Schwarz, Witten Volume 1, section 3.2, BRST quantization is introduced in a general way. A Lie algebra $G$ is defined with elements
$$ [K_i,K_j] = f_{ij}{}^k K_k \tag{3.2.1}$$
where $f_{ij}{}^k$ is the structure constant. Antighosts $b_i$ and ghosts $c^i$ transform in the adjoint and dual adjoint representations respectively. They obey
$$ \{c^i,b_j\} = \delta^i_j\tag{3.2.2} $$
The nilpotent BRST operator is
$$ Q = c^i K_i - \frac{1}{2}f_{ij}{}^kc^i c^j b_k \tag{3.2.4}$$
The indices here are all summed.

This is then applied to the Virasoro algebra without central charge
$$ [L_m,L_n] = (m-n)L_{m+n} $$
where
$$ L_m = L^{(\alpha)}_m + L^{(c)}_m - a\delta_m \tag{3.1.58}$$
The ghost contribution is
$$ L^{(c)}_m = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(m-n)b_{m+n}c_{-n} \tag{3.1.49} $$
According to the book, the BRST operator is
\begin{align*}
Q &= \sum_{-\infty}^\infty L^{(\alpha)}_{-m}c_m - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty (m-n):c_{-m} c_{-n} b_{m+n} : -ac_0 \tag{3.2.11}\\
&= \sum_{-\infty}^\infty :(L^{(\alpha)}_{-m} + \frac{1}{2}L^{(c)}_{-m} - a\delta_m)c_m: \tag{3.2.12}
\end{align*}

It seems that the antighosts $b_i$ are now $b_m$, and the ghosts $c^i$ are now $c_{-m}$, so that $$\{c_m,b_n\}=\delta_{m+n}\tag{3.1.44}.$$ The non-zero structure constants are $f_{mn}^{(m+n)} = (m-n)$.

**My question is**: how is the normal ordered ghost term derived? I think the ghost contribution to the Virasoro operator should be normal ordered, since the ordering ambiguity is adsorbed into $a$. So, following equation $(3.2.4)$,
\begin{align}
Q &= \sum_{-\infty}^\infty c_{-m}L_m - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} (m-n)c_{-m}c_{-n}b_{m+n} \\
&= \sum_{-\infty}^\infty L^{(\alpha)}_{-m} c_{m} + \sum_{-\infty}^\infty c_{-m}L^{(c)}_m - ac_0 - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} (m-n)c_{-m}c_{-n}b_{m+n}
\end{align}

Inserting $L^{(c)}_m$, it seems that 
\begin{align}
\sum_{-\infty}^\infty (m-n) c_{-m}:b_{m+n}c_{-n}: - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}(m-n)c_{-m}c_{-n}b_{m+n} &= -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{-\infty}^\infty (m-n) : c_{-m}c_{-n}b_{m+n}: 
\end{align}

I am unsure as to how to relate these. It seems that trying to combine the two terms will give a $-3/2$ since the operators are anticommuting, as well as a divergence sum. Perhaps equation $(3.1.49)$ is off by some factor? Above that equation it is written that $L_m = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^\pi_{-\pi} d\sigma e^{im\sigma} T_{++}$, and computing this I get $i$ times equation $(3.1.49)$.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Well, the string BRST operator (3.2.11-12) with an *infinite*-dimensional Lie algebra cannot be adapted from the BRST operator (3.2.4) for *finite*-dimensional Lie algebras as it stands, mostly because the second term in the latter does not use [normal ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order). The issue is quite grave since the difference between the second term 
   $$\tag{1} Q_2~=~-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n,m\in\mathbb{Z}} (m-n) c_{-m}c_{-n}b_{m+n}$$
   *without* normal ordering and the corresponding second term *with* normal ordering is infinite:

$$\tag{2} Q_2~-~:Q_2:~=~c_0 \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} n c_{-n} b_n ~-~ :c_0 \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} n c_{-n} b_n: ~=~ \infty~c_0.$$

2. The most powerful method is instead to formulate the BRST symmetry with the help of [OPEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion), radial ordering ${\cal R}$, and [Wick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem) between radial and normal ordering. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29716/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24157/2451) Phys.SE posts and links therein. The BRST charge operator is $$\tag{3} Q~=~\oint \frac{dz}{2\pi i}~ j_{\rm BRST}(z),$$
   where the BRST current operator
   $$\tag{4} j_{\rm BRST}(z)~=~ c(z)T^{(X)}(z) + \frac{1}{2} :b(z)c(z)\partial c(z): + \frac{3}{2} \partial^2 c(z) $$ 
   is a primary field of conformal weight $h=1$, which satisfies the OPE
   $${\cal R}~ j_{\rm BRST}(z)~j_{\rm BRST}(w)
   ~=~ -\frac{c^{(X)}-18}{2(z-w)^3}c(w)\partial c(w)- \frac{c^{(X)}-18}{4(z-w)^2}c(w)\partial^2 c(w)
   - \frac{c^{(X)}-26}{12(z-w)}c(w)\partial^3 c(w) +\text{non-singular terms}.\tag{5} $$
   Here 
   $$\tag{6} c(z)~=~ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} c_n z^{-n+1}, \qquad b(z)~=~ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} b_n z^{-n-2}. $$
   The BRST charge operator $Q$ is famously nilpotent $Q^2=0$ iff the matter central charge $c^{(X)}=26$ is [twenty-six](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosonic_string_theory).

References:

1. M.B. Green, J.H. Schwarz and E. Witten, *Superstring theory,* Vol. 1, 1986; Sections 3.1 & 3.2.
2. J. Polchinski, *String Theory,* Vol. 1, 1998; Section 4.3.

Comment: 3. R. Blumenhagen, D. Lust and S. Theisen, _Basic Concepts of String Theory,_ 2013; Section 5.2.